# When using Video.js is there any way I can avoid the webpage content alert?

Tags: security, sharepoint-2007, alert, video.js

I'm trying to use Video.js to display a small video on our team sharepoint page (Sharepoint 2007). It works great, but the '*Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?*' alert always displays when you navigate to the page. The security settings on the computers cannot be changed, but is there any way I can avoid this alert being displayed?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the page being accessed is served over HTTPS, but some content loaded remotely comes from HTTP. If you're using the Video.js CDN-hosted files, you'd want to change the include tags to look like this:

```
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video.js"></script>
```

These are called [protocol relative urls](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), meaning it will use whatever protocol the page is to load the files.

Hope that helps!